# How to save a ssh session's whole echo history over tty to a file?

Tags: ssh, command-line

I `ssh` connect to a Linux server and want to save all the output from the server tty(console) to a log file, for later read/search.

For example, if I do `echo "dafds"` and then `ls` in `bash`, I want the log file to have the following content, or maybe something similar:

```
bash-4.4$ echo "dafds"
dafds
bash-4.4$ ls
README.md
```

After I leave this session, this file should have all the contents I saw over the terminal during this session.

Can I achieve this?

Should I do this on server side or on client side? Thanks.

Comment: you can just redirect individual commands to a file like `echo 'foo bar' > output.txt`

Comment: Can I do this for every command I execute for this ssh session, if I do not want to redirect the output and also see the content in the file?

Comment: Yes, you can basically append the std output of each command using `>>` ie `echo "foo " >> output.txt` and `echo "bar " >> output.txt` will create a file which will have "foo bar " in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) to read from stdin and stdout and redirect to a log file:

`ssh user@server | tee ssh_session.out`

Assuming that you know before making the connection that you want to log the session.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use tmux for this.

`:capture-pane -S 100` save the lasts 100 lines in a buffer.

`:save-buffer filename.txt` write this buffer on a file.